# Disable rate limiter in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to disable rate limiting on every/individual routes in Laravel?

I'm trying to test an endpoint that receives a lot of requests, but randomly Laravel will start responding with `{ status: 429, responseText: 'Too Many Attempts.' }` for a few hundred requests which makes testing a huge pain.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

In `app/Http/Kernel.php` Laravel has a default throttle limit for all api routes.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Comment or increase it.

Comment: If I comment is it means it would be no limit?

Comment: Correct. Commented out means no limit.

Comment: This approach is _strongly_ unadvised unless your application logic has a specific reason to change throttling. If you want to turn off throttling for testing, use: `$this->withoutMiddleware()->get($url, $data);`.

Comment: commenting it out does not appear to mean no limit on my recent test

Comment: Is there a way to reset throttle once the limit is reached? I changed my system date to 2 months ahead to test something out and now "Retry-After" response HTTP Header indicates that I have to wait for 2 months to access API routes.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, but instead Mostafa's. This changes ALL environments, not just testing. In the question OP clearly states he want's to test.

Comment: This probably isnt a best practice for real world scenario outside of testing, correct?

Answer (score 80):

You can actually disable *only* a certain middleware in tests.

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;

class YourTest extends TestCase 
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withoutMiddleware(
            ThrottleRequests::class
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because this is the right way to test something like this. Disabling the Throttle limit globally is not a good practice.

Comment: Laravel 5.5+ required

Comment: Very good answer, but..what about some more info on where and how to use this code?

Comment: @LachezarTodorov This won't work for E2E testing, however, where the tested application is running separate of the testing code. Selectively disabling throttling through environment config, etc. is a more wholistic approach.

Comment: I guess you will want to have enabled Throttle on E2E testing.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you are using the API routes then you can change the throttle in app/Http/Kernel.php or take it off entirely.  If you need to throttle for the other routes you can register the middleware for them separately.

(example below: throttle - 60 attempts then locked out for 1 minute)

```
'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use `cache:clear` command to clear your cache including your rate limits, like so:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Laravel 8.x or later you can use RateLimiter with the following steps:

In your app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php find below
configureRateLimiting:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{

    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
    });

    // no limit throttle
    RateLimiter::for('none', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::none();
    });

}
```

In your app/web.php add 'throttle:none:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'throttle:none']], function ($router) {
    Route::post('test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for api routes

Comment: It will run into `api` limiter first, then it run into `none` limiter. Thus, this approach won't work

Comment: I have mentioned both approaches and in case we don't need any limit please use the later part `no limit throttle`

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 5.7

**Dynamic Rate Limiting**
You may specify a dynamic request maximum based on an attribute of the authenticated User model. For example, if your User model contains a rate_limit attribute, you may pass the name of the attribute to the throttle middleware so that it is used to calculate the maximum request count:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:rate_limit,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#rate-limiting

Comment: I tried it in Laravel 5.4 and it worked, but for some reason it was using half the value I put in.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to disable just for automated tests, you can use the `WithoutMiddleware` trait on your tests.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class YourTest extends TestCase {
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    ...
```

Otherwise, just remove the `'throttle:60,1',` line from your *Kernel* file (`app/Http/Kernel.php`), and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I just changed the default value of `perMinute()` in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.

```php
protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            $perMinute = env('APP_ENV') === 'testing' ? 1000 : 60;

            return Limit::perMinute($perMinute)
              ->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
```

Comment: `env('APP_ENV')` will not work perfectly if cache is enabled. Doc has this bool check `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::environment('testing') ? 1000 : 60;`

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following lines in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
    'api' => [
        'throttle:120,1',
        'bindings',
         \App\Library\Cobalt\Http\Middleware\LogMiddleware::class,
    ],
```

If the problem persists try the artisan command `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 2):

A non-hacky way to increase the throttle in unit tests to avoid the dreaded 429:

1. Remove the throttle:60,1 from the kernel file middleware.
2. Add the throttle middleware back in to the route group, using an environment variable instead:

```
$requestsPerMinute = ENV("REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE", 60);
Route::middleware(["auth:api", "throttle:$requestsPerMinute,1"])->group(function(){
  // your routes
});
```

3. Define the REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE environment variable much higher in phpunit.xml, to allow more requests in test environment before throttling.

```
<server name="REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE" value="500"/>
```

4. (Also define the new REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE var in .env, even though it'll fall back to 60).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your RouteServiceProvider (app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)

and then increse the Rate to remove it
fro this

```
 RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
     return Limit::perMinute(60);
});
```

to this for example

```
 RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
     return Limit::perMinute(600);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can remove or comment out the line `(throttle:60,1)` from App\Http\Kernel.php.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same solution as the accepted answer from 5 years ago.