# Laravel API rate limit weirdness

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Route rate limiting (throttling) was added in 5.2.

Docs were only really added in 5.6:
[Laravel 5.6 Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#rate-limiting)

The docs seem to say that it's specified 
`number of requests,number of minutes`

> The throttle middleware accepts two parameters that determine the
>   maximum number of requests that can be made in a given number of
>   minutes.

This answer [Disable rate limiter in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058706/3515394) and this blog [API rate limiting in Laravel 5.2](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/api-rate-limiting-in-laravel-5-2/) then pointed out it's
`number of requests per minute,number of minutes lockout`

Through experimenting with this (in Laravel 5.2), and logging when we get rate-limited, it seems to not be per rolling minute as you'd think.

So if you have one periodic request every 59 seconds, the counter will continue counting down, even though it is only one request per minute. Instead, you need to not send any requests for a full minute - only then will the counter reset.

Has anybody else ever had issues with this?