# exception "ThrottleRequests" errors to many request in api laravel

Tags: laravel-5, throttling

Since many devices have the same ip address request on the api server, I have a bug to many requests, there is a way to customize the "throttle" that the request is from a single device sent to the server. help me

Comment: Yes, you can change the default throttle setting in `/app/Http/Kernel.php` file. You can either remove or write your own throttle setting where you can exclude counting for the same IPs.

Comment: @CanCelik can you give me a specific example about it? thanks for you

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel