# loop send request many time with Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have 400 records I want to insert to a database server by call web service on a server. But when I loop insert by call web service I got an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
>   error 429 Too Many Requests

I try this code:

```
$http =  new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $response = $http->post('http://192.168.1.33/APIServer/public/api/data', [
            'form_params' => $value,
            ]); 
        }
```

All records I loops are 400 rows. How can I insert all the record via a call that web service with Guzzle. Thank beforehand.

Comment: If the server on which you are sending data doesn't have bulk insert endpoint, you can add wait function in your loop to make some delay between requests.

Comment: @AndriiFilenko please create answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Send all data into the bulk way one request call and do foreach at your server end. so you not need to send to many requests on the server.
2. the second one is you can `remove request limit` on that route from the Laravel so it allows you to send many requests in sequence

   For this, you can follow this: [Disable rate limiter in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel)

Comment: how about PHP with guzzle how to remove request limit?

Comment: Or If in laravel then refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel

Comment: Or if you use core php then you need to refere this link https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/resolving-429-many-requests/

Answer (score 0):

If the server on which you are sending data doesn't have bulk insert endpoint, you can add [wait](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function in your loop to make some delay between requests.

Answer (score 0):

The `GuzzleHttp` client throws exception based on the response code send by the server. In your case the 3rd party is sending you a response with `429` status code after certain number of requests. This is then thrown back by `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException`.

To resolve this, you can use queued jobs with delay, create a job `SendApiRequest` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendApiRequest extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * \GuzzleHttp\Client
     */
    private $http;

    /**
     * Data array
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * Url string
     */
    private $url = 'http://192.168.1.33/APIServer/public/api/data';

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Client $http, array $data)
    {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->data = $data;

    }

    /**
     * Create a new peerreview
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $response = $this->http->post($this->url, $data);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

And then you can call the api using delayed job queue (Lets say 3rd party allows only 60 requests per minute at max :

```
$rateLimitPerMinute  = 60; 
$http =  new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$counter = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    $delayInMinutes = intval($counter/$rateLimitPerMinute);

    SendApiRequest::dispatch($http, $value)->delay(now()->addMinutes($delayInMinutes));

    $counter++;
}
```

Also as a side note, you can add a logging mechanism once you get response in the job. It is important to store that data so you can refer it later anytime you see problem.

Comment: how about PHP with guzzle which path should i change?

Comment: Pretty sure OP is asking for rate-limiting on consuming remote API with Guzzle, and not being on the receiving end.

Comment: Is the `192.168.1.33` an IP you do not have control over? Like its a 3rd party API or its your own server/

Comment: @MihirBhende yes it's third party that i call

Comment: My bad, I thought its your on server : let me update my answer.

Comment: @MihirBhende ok

Comment: @MihirBhende i use PHP how to do that wil model?

Comment: You mean you are using core php and not laravel?