# How to avoid ThrottleRequestsException in Laravel unit test?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am working on an application that has date logic within i.e something will be returned from the database based on the date, and only the relevant data for that date should be returned. How would I go about unit testing this? There are 24 dates that return 24 different pieces of data, I thought maybe doing something like this,

```php
public function testGetActiveData()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    //Create the data
    $dates = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-12-01', '2019-12-12');
    $start_date = new Carbon("2019-12-01 00:00:00");

    $dates->forEach(function($date){
        $data = factory(Data::class)->create([
            'date_playable' => $date->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
        factory(LinkedData::class, 15)->create([
            'data_id' => $data->id
        ]);
    });

    for($day = 1; $day <= 24; $day++) {
        if($day = 1) {
            Cache::put('data_date', $start_date->toDateTimeString(), now()->addMinutes(30));
        } else {
            Cache::put('data_date', $start_date->toDateTimeString()->addDays($day), now()->addMinutes(30));
        }

        $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/data');

        $response->assertJson(['date_playable' => Cache::get('data_date')]);

    }
}
```

However this errors due to too many attempts, is there a better way to test this? An obvioulsy I am testing dates in the future so I am pushing a "future date" into cache and then using that is there a better of doing that also?

Comment: What was the actual error message you get?

Comment: @KoalaYeung Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException : Too Many Attempts.

Comment: Try changing `$this->json('GET', '/api/data');` to `$this->withoutMiddleware()->json('GET', '/api/data');` and see if it avoided the exception.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this comment of a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel#comment86418420_43058691), you may disable the default Laravel rate limit in your test by applying [withoutMiddleware](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_withoutMiddleware) before the [TestCase](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html) `get` or `json` calls.

```php
public function testGetActiveData()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    //Create the data
    $dates = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-12-01', '2019-12-12');
    $start_date = new Carbon("2019-12-01 00:00:00");

    $dates->forEach(function($date){
        $data = factory(Data::class)->create([
            'date_playable' => $date->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
        factory(LinkedData::class, 15)->create([
            'data_id' => $data->id
        ]);
    });

    for($day = 1; $day <= 24; $day++) {
        if($day = 1) {
            Cache::put('data_date', $start_date->toDateTimeString(), now()->addMinutes(30));
        } else {
            Cache::put('data_date', $start_date->toDateTimeString()->addDays($day), now()->addMinutes(30));
        }

        // circumvent the throttle rate limit middleware
        // with the "withoutMiddleware" method
        $response = $this->withoutMiddleware()->json('GET', '/api/data');

        $response->assertJson(['date_playable' => Cache::get('data_date')]);

    }
}
```