# Laravel application response with 429 http-status-code

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-429

I have a web application (Angular front, Laravel backend API). In that there is a section where I have messaging system. Basically four user roles can post and read messages.

When a user logged in I needs to check every 10 seconds to see if there are new messages for any user of any role(out of 4 roles).

This works fine but from time to time I get http status code of 429 Too many request. I have no idea what is the reason. Anyone have an idea of what is the reason or can point me to the right direction in order to fix this?

Note: I have a custom field system build and I use that to hold extra data of messages. I notice that when i fetch messages considerable number of models related to custom fields also quarried. Can this be a reason?

Comment: you can try this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel
But it won't be a good approach in my opinion. I'm not very familiar with angular but as I remember there is a way that you can subscribe to an event so that if something changed in that event, you'll get the changes. My suggestion is to use that method rather than calling the end point for each 10 seconds.

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha Thank you. subscribe to an event is a feature of Angular? I will check that. I don't like to use the option given in that stackoverflow answer, instead I am going to log requests and see if can find the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and here are my steps.

1. I needed to find all my request going to the API, for that I installed this package [API logger](https://github.com/aungwinthant/apilogger). Using this I examined the requests and there I found some request made to the API over and over.
2. I corrected the requests made to the API and the issue seems to fixed.