# Laravel: Remove Request Throttling For Authenticated Users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I wish to disable request throttling for users that are authenticated through the API.

Kernel:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:240,1'
    ],
];
```

Throttle here will limit the requests to 240 per minute regardless of whether or not a user is authenticated.

How would it be possible to do this so it only throttles unauthenticated users?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21629

Comment: For Laravel 10 'excluded_middleware' => 'throttle:api'  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67996725/7284577

Answer (score 4):

For the latest version of Laravel 8.x. We can use RateLimiter with the following steps:

1. In your *app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php* find below configureRateLimiting:

```
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {

        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });

        // Add this for no limit throttle
        RateLimiter::for('none', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::none();
        });

    }
```

2. In your *app/web.php* add 'throttle:none':

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => ['auth', 'throttle:none'],
  ], function ($router) {
    Route::post('test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

3. This step is optional, If you are using other middleware you can group them up in your app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'no_throttle' => [
            'throttle:none',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => ['auth', 'no_throttle'],
  ], function ($router) {
    Route::post('test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pack all auth routes to one group and set throttle to unlimited or in your controller class constructor you can disable ThrottleRequests middleware.

Please check this thread:
[Disable rate limiter in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel)