# How to disable throttle in specific routes? (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

Can we disable the laravel's throttle in a specific group of routes?

Here are my codes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::get('/sample1', 'SampleController@sample');
    // more routes here
});
```

I want to disable throttle limiter in all routes wrap inside `Route::group`. Can we possibly do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Latest laravel version then you disable throtle for specific route group.

You can exclude `throttle:api` middleware for specific route group using `excluded_middleware`

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum'],
'excluded_middleware' => 'throttle:api'], function () {
      Route::get('/sample1', 'SampleController@sample');
    });
```