# Load test Laravel application with jmeter

Tags: laravel, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to load test a Laravel application, however I'm stuck at the very beginning. I am attempting a login with a POST request, but I'm always getting response code: 419. I have googled and asked around a bit to no avail.

So far, I have extracted the xsrf token from the GET request and am trying to append it as a header to the POST request. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, however.[image: Header Manager]

That's what my header manager looks like, I looked at the post request through dev tools when doing it manually and I tried to replicate it.[image: Request body]
[image: Request headers]

I really can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I don't think I can fix this by using a different tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web routes you need to [Disable CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it), or put csrf on the jmeter.

For API routes you need to [disable rate limiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel). Just go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and comment `throttle:60,1` line

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...
    'api' => [
//        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Maybe you should disable these on test environment only, in most cases in the production these feature is needed.

Comment: I really don't think it's either of the two. I'm trying with just one user and it's not working. The page is not csrf protected besides, at least not as far as I can tell.