# Laravel testing - 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8, laravel-testing

As I move forward in my Laravel project I have several tests for controllers and now I'm facing with this issue.

Some of my tests are failing with this message:

```
Expected response status code [200] but received 429.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 429.
```

I tried to solve with these methods:

1. Add `withoutMiddleware()` to `TestCase.php`:

```php
public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->withoutMiddleware(
        ThrottleRequests::class
    );
}
```

2. Add `REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE` to `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<phpunit>
  <php>
    ...
    <server name="REQUESTS_PER_MINUTE" value="500"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

3. Change my dockerized nginx config for this:

```
server {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    }
}
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=100r/s;
```

Neither solution helped.

I don't want to change the Laravel's throttle settings only because of testing. I think here need to be a valid solution for this without changing the framework's settings.

Any suggestion how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code that is giving you problems ? What test ?

Comment: Mostly controller tests. Get, pos5, put and delete http requests. Nothing special.

Comment: Did you modify how the Middleware works? What is your `phpunit.xml`? (share it without important keys please). Have you changed the behaviour of the class `TestCase` or similar (did you modify anything about the Laravel TestCase class?)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I didn't modify the Middleware. I didn't modify the `phpunit.xml`, only add the line what I wrote. The `TestCase` is modified a several functions, like `mockSuperUser()`, `mockUnauthorizedUser()`, `setHeaders()` and some similar of these. These functions are not affected on behavior of TestCase, they are just "global" functions for testing. In the TestCase `setUp()`  I run this two things: `$this->seed();` and then `$this->withoutMiddleware(ThrottleRequests::class);`. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank's solution works but makes not possible to use named limiters. Code below passes correct arguments list and allow to detect named limiters

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis;

class ThrottleRequests extends ThrottleRequestsWithRedis
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1, $prefix = '')
    {
        if (app()->environment('production')) {
            return parent::handle(...func_get_args());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this, although not the most elegant was to replace the ThrottleMiddleware with my own and checking the env for testing, effectively disabling laravel's throttling for for phpunit. :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis;
use Closure;

class ThrottleRequests extends ThrottleRequestsWithRedis
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1, $prefix = '')
    {
        if (config('app.env') === 'testing') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next, $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes, $prefix);
    }
}
```

You will then need to update your `kernel.php` to use your new class e.g.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'throttle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
...
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I was currently facing this same issue testing with Laravel 9.

I solved it adding inside the 'configureRateLimiting()' method in 'RouteServiceProvider.php' the following code:

```
RateLimiter::for('test', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(XX)->by($request->ip());
});
```

Replace the 'XX' with the max amount of API requests per minute you want to allow during testing.

After that run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

So today I ran into the same issue on laravel 10 and found this amazing answer but for some reason it was not top result for me.

answer by @Mostafa Bahri
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369024/17809957use

```
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;

class YourTest extends TestCase 
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withoutMiddleware(
            ThrottleRequests::class
        );
    }
    ...
}
```